# How can I mine on the rinkeby testnet?

Tags: mining, rinkeby

Maybe my question is way off base here, because I'm an ethereum novice.  I would like to run miners on the rinkeby testnet.  I'm more interested in getting the mining process up and running and exploring the effects of that.  I know there are better ways of getting ethereum - that's not why I'm mining.

If anyone can offer pointers or advice on how to set up miners on the testnet, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rinkeby doesn't run Proof of Work, it runs Proof of Authority. This means there are no miners. The people that create blocks are pre-authorized nodes. It's a network where pre-selected and trusted people are allowed to create the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm VERY late to this, but you can do a couple things to get testnet eth:

- Mine ETH for yourself on rospsten, it's somewhat easy to do but can be time consuming and resource intensive (power and computing)
- Use a faucet like this one: https://faucet.egorfine.com
- You can also buy ropsten eth with tools like [ropsten.money](https://www.ropsten.money/l/ropsten) (full disclosure: I made ropsten.money)

Comment: The question is quite clear it is about mining and not getting ether.